# Apollo GraphQL useQuery hook triggered with old variables

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client, react-usememo

I am trying to make some reusable Apollo hooks and simplify the APIs with some encapsulation. So my idea is to have the `useQuery` hook inside of a custom hook. In my case I need actually the `useLazyQuery` hook:

```
export const useGetSomething = () => {
  const [something, setSomething] = useState<Something>();
  const [getSomething, { data, refetch }] =
    useLazyQuery<GetSomethingHook>(GET_SOMETHING_QUERY, {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.something) {
      setSomething(data.something);
    }
  }, [setSomething, data]);

  const loadSomething = useCallback(
    (id: string, date: Date) => {
      getSomething({
        variables: {
          args: {
            id,
            date,
          },
        },
      });
    },
    [getSomething],
  );

  const refetchSomething = useCallback(
    (id: string, date: Date) => {
      refetch({
        variables: {
          args: {
            id,
            date,
          },
        },
      }).then((result) => setSomething(result.data.something))
    },
    [setSomething, refetch],
  );

  return useMemo(() => {
    return {
      loadSomething,
      refetchSomething,
      something,
    };
  }, [something, loadSomething, refetchSomething]);
};
```

So there is a range of issues:

- if I use `refetch` with the same `id` and a new `date`, the `useLazyQuery` calls for the `something` with the old date that was the initial one (why? no idea...)
- if I replace `refetch` with `fetchMore` in `refetchSomething`, the call is actually done properly AT FIRST, but then there is a weird another call without ANY actual source in that hook which calls for `something` with old `date`
- if I use `getSomething` in both `loadSomething` and `refetchSomething` it works like `fetchMore` where even tho the function was called only once, the `Network` tab shows two calls - one with old and second with new data.

It just looks like `Apollo` is just broken.

Answer (score -1):

It's not that Apollo is broken, it's that you've what I call a lifecycle hell with useMemo and useCallback.

I'm not sure to understand why you are passing `setSomething`,  `getSomething` and `refetch` as dependencies to your callbacks.

If you want `loadSomething` and `refetchSomething` to update with new args, then past your args props as dependencies, not your functions.

Comment: You need to provide every variable that changes to the dependency array as it is required by React hooks documentation. If you have linting turned on and you don't do that, you will get a linting error. And your comment is not really helpful here to be honest, because it still does not explain why this way it's wrong. Yes, I could use use hook arguments instead of function arguments, but there is no apparent reason why the second approach would not work it makes your life harder as the hook has to be positioned in a way to have access to those args during init, not as callback.

Comment: Ludivin please refer to hooks documentation where it is said: "We recommend using the exhaustive-deps rule as part of our eslint-plugin-react-hooks package. It warns when dependencies are specified incorrectly and suggests a fix."